# Indentation checkstyle error on array initializer argument

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm having an issue when defining an annotation that contains array initializer.
The error is

> '}' has incorrect indentation level 0, expected level should be 8.[IndentationCheck]

about this line:

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {
        Initializer.class
}, loader = ConfigContextLoader.class)
```

and the indentation configuration used is

```
<property name="basicOffset" value="4"/>
<property name="braceAdjustment" value="0"/>
<property name="caseIndent" value="4"/>
<property name="throwsIndent" value="4"/>
<property name="arrayInitIndent" value="4"/>
<property name="lineWrappingIndentation" value="8"/>
```

I don't understand why wouldn't it work, as when I'm creating a simple array initializer everything works

```
int[] initializers = {
        4
};
```

What i'm missing here? Thanks!

Comment: `initializers` is the parameter you assign to, so the array initialisation is already nested once.

Comment: Why isn't there is a problem with the second example then?

Comment: In the second case there are no nest parentheses: `(int[] initializers = ...)`

Comment: Yup I know it, but why would parentheses affect the way inner content, its not a line wrapping or something, just initializer indentation.

Comment: The same reason for `f(...\n\t\t...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to report the issue at https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues , but it most likely won't be fixed anytime soon as there are 48 other open issues for this check. https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aindentation